# How to call an update procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
create procedure colupdate (
    @firstname varchar(200),
    @status varchar(200)
)
as 
begin 
    select Firstname,Lastname,status from tbl_Students
    where Firstname=@Firstname
    update tbl_Students
    set status= @status
    where @firstname=Firstname 
end
```

and I call it like:

```
execute colupdate 'Vikek','deactivate'
```

Now I get "zero rows updated".

How can I update like this?

Comment: The obvious thing to infer is that there's no row with a `Firstname` of `Vikek`.

Comment: Also, your `select` statement does nothing here

Comment: You don't do anything with the rows returned by your select, so why are you doing a select?

Comment: Well the select statement (potentially) returns rows to the caller ...

Comment: Also, your update statement should be like  `update tbl_Students set status= @status where Firstname = @firstname`, not the other way round.

Comment: On top of what others already said, you might want to use consistent variable naming. `@firstname` is not the same as `@Firstname`, and your script might break if you switch it between servers of different collations.

Answer (score 0):

May this one help you out

```
create procedure colupdate (
          @firstname varchar(200),
          @status varchar(200)
)
as 
begin 
    IF EXISTS(select Firstname,Lastname,status from tbl_Students where Firstname=@Firstname)
        update tbl_Students set status= @status where Firstname=@Firstname Else
Print ' data not exist'
    end
```

Comment: Thank you to have a look at my answer. Sorry for the error . I misplace the update statement. I am updating my answer .